# display text as square symbols instead of letters

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-family

Is there a simple css way to display text with every letter replaced with a filled square?

My idea was to find a font-family that has squares for all letters, but I didn't find anything like that existing. Google is no friend as it gives hits of posted issues with boxes that appear when fonts fail in some way.

Letters should be displayed as squares, not replaced with squares. Also, I need to be able to control the square fill color with the usual html/css.

I'm fine to use font-face, but am trying to avoid the learning curve for creating my own font.

Update: here is an example:

```
div.innerHTML = "some arbitrary text".
```

Should be displayed like this:

```
"■■■■ ■■■■■■■■■ ■■■■".
```

Comment: `I need to` is generally a bad way to ask a question unless you provide us with what you have tried so far.....!!

Comment: please use http://fontawesome.io/.

Comment: @NoobEditor: I have googled for quite a long while. But the problem is that all results are about people that don't get their fonts properly displayed. I'm sure there must be an existing font-family, was just trying to find that. Does that help?

Comment: @Nikhil great pointer, thanks. But I understand that this would allow me to assign a square to one letter - not to all letters in my text? I'll research this anyway.

Comment: @bebbi - if you want only square icon...u can download it only...please visit the site :http://fontello.com/

Comment: @Nikhil another great pointer! Guess I'll just have to dig deep and find out how to create my own font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NoobEditor is right although. Many online font editors available (e.g.: http://fontark.net/farkwp/ ), you can create such font family in few minutes and can embed with your app.

Comment: cool, thanks. I'm sure for front-end people this is all very obvious stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get a square font, define it in your we page style, asign it to an object, a div must work, put your text there. Voila.

Comment: Thanks - what does "define it in your web page style" refer to?

Comment: Somethig loke this 

@font-face {
    font-family: 'font_name';
    src: url('./fonts/your_font');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Comment: @Xavi, font-family looks for font on the client side, so if the user has not the square font, it wont work. He nust define own font.

Comment: @Trash Bean that's it - but I was struggling to find the './fonts/your_font' part

Comment: That's your font, just upload it wherever you want on your site. May be you have to define it in diferent ways, up to the browser you need:
    src: url('../fonts/font.eot'); 
    src: local("font"), url('../fonts/font.ttf');

Comment: @Trash Bean Thanks - I think I'm ok with the css declaration, but I guess I'll have to dig into how I can create a font.

Comment: Here you are [link](http://www.myscriptfont.com/), other thing is look for some free font (dafont or something like this).